# How to check if an Array with Object contains a Property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm coding a decentralized app and i'm stuck.
Here is my problem : i'm calling with async function and return an array with object :

```
const result = [
{ trait_type: "Neck Gear", value: "1" },
{ trait_type: "Alpha Score", value: "6" },
{ trait_type: "Generation", value: "Gen 0" },];
```

I need to access the line "Alpha score". I have to check if alpha score exist in this object.
So i did this :

```
async function checkAlpha() {
    try {
        const checkAlphaTxn = await traitsContract.compileAttributes([4]) 
                    .then((result) => {
                        // console.log(result.hasOwnProperty("Alpha Score")) //return false
                        console.log(result) //return array above
                    })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I wanted to use the .hasOwnProperty() method but it returns to me FALSE. But alpha score value exist.

Thank you in advance for those who can unblock me ! :)

Comment: `Alpha Score` is not a property of `result` array, it's the value of one of the properties

Answer (score 2):

`hasOwnProperty` checks an *object* - you have an *array of objects* where `Alpha Score` is actually the value of one of the properties of one of the objects

```
console.log(result.find(r => r.trait_type == "Alpha Score"))
```

Comment: And there's no duplicate? OP is the first asking about this type of problem?

Comment: I have tried your solution, it return in the console : TypeError: results.find is not a function
    at checkAlpha

Maybe because i'm coding with React ?

Comment: @Tristan react does not change javascript! If you get that message then `results` is not an array.

Comment: Oh yes that's it ! I tried `console.log(typeof results)` and it return me STRING.

But i don't understand why the answer look like an Array who contains objects...

Comment: Try doing `JSON.parse` on the string before calling `find`

Comment: YES it works ! JSON.parse was the solution.
My function returns a string array => so i use JSON.parse(results) and now i can use find so it works. Thank you a lot

Comment: @Tristan glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

hasOwnProperty is used for checking **keys** like `trait_type`; not **values** like 'Alpha Score'.

Instead, you can just find an object for which the value for `trait_type` is equal to "Alpha Score", and then access the `value` property of the resulting trait object. You can do this using `.find`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=nl

```js
const getResults = async () => {
  return [
    { trait_type: "Neck Gear", value: "1" },
    { trait_type: "Alpha Score", value: "6" },
    { trait_type: "Generation", value: "Gen 0" }
  ];
};

(async () => {
  const results = await getResults();
  
  const alphaScoreTrait = results.find(t => t.trait_type === "Alpha Score");

  if (!alphaScoreTrait) {
    console.log("No trait found with type 'Alpha Score'");
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(alphaScoreTrait.value); // 6
})();
```

Comment: I have tried this solutions too.. but it return : TypeError: results.find is not a function at checkAlpha

I have tried with some() and filter(), they don't work too :(